# Manually set system time while NTP sync is on

Tags: time, ntp

I have a computer without internet connection and I would like to manually set the system time. I've tried running `timedatectl set-time`, but I get

```
Failed to set time: Automatic time synchronization is enabled
```

While this is true, the NTP server is not available, so the time is not actually updating. I don't want to disable NTP synchronization, as I would like the computer to synchronize when it regains internet connection. Which would be the best way to manually set system time while keeping NTP sync on?

Can I just do `timedatectl set-ntp false`, set the time and then run `timedatectl set-ntp true`, or is there a better solution to this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it that you cannot connect to an NTP server specifically?  Or is it that you cannot connect to any of the NTP servers out there?  There are many servers out there to choose from.  Those can be set in the `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf`

Comment: @Terrance in my case the computer is (for a few weeks) on a very restricted network which unfortunately does not allow NTP traffic. So I cannot reach an NTP server at all. I would love to set the system time manually for now, but that's really difficult since timedatectl effectively prevents this.